# jQuery and Javascript If/Else

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I am trying to get a simple (at least should be simple) If/Else statement to work in jQuery.

The basic gist of what I need is that "If" a certain "div" is added to a page then a class gets added to another div.
Otherwise the div has "remove" applied to it and does not show up on the page.

Here is my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery){
if(jQuery('#myExtraContent4').length){
    jQuery('#ks_footer').addClass('ifThere');
},
else {
    jQuery('#ks_footer').remove();
}
});
```

What ends up happening is that the class of "ifThere" gets applied properly, but the div "#ks_footer" does not get removed if nothing is added to it. (It is always there even when it is empty and should be removed)

I am hoping someone can spot why and offer a suggestion on how to correct.

Thanks
Gary

Comment: doesn't it have to be like this ".length()" ?

Comment: Nope, `.length` is a property, not a function: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_length_string.asp

Comment: @JanWiemers, it's `size()`, but `length` can also be used (it's a native js property, tough)

Comment: @Jasper `length` is a property, but in this case it's jQuery length, not string length.

Comment: Er, the comma just before the `else`, is it a typo? If not, please try removing it! Otherwise there is nothing wrong in your code

Comment: @mblase75 yeah `.length` returns the number of elements in an array if it's used on an array.

Comment: @Jasper jQuery objects aren't arrays either! :-)

Comment: Ok, rightly said, here is a proper link: http://api.jquery.com/length/

Comment: yeah you are right, i should take a loo befor post something :D

Answer (score 4):

```
jQuery(function($){
    if($('#myExtraContent4').length > 0){
        $('#ks_footer').addClass('ifThere');
    }//, <--this comma should not be here so I've commented it out
    else {
        $('#ks_footer').remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: Bingo! ... I thought that I had even tried it without the comma, but for some reason it worked just now.

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery){
    if(jQuery('#myExtraContent4').length){
        jQuery('#ks_footer').addClass('ifThere');
    }
    //, remove , in between if and else
    else {
        jQuery('#ks_footer').remove();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove the `#ks_footer` DIV if it does not contain child elements, you could use

```
var div = document.getElementById('#ks_footer')
if(!div.children.length) { div.parentNode.removeChild(div); }
```

Please excuse me if it is pure JS not jQuery, but I'm really more comfortable with it...